# заменить физический датчик программой

Tags: python, сервер, sensor

пишу pet проект.
есть физические датчики sonoff с wifi. при подключении их в сеть их внутренний модуль выдает ip и по этому ip я могу отправлять запросы на него в виде ip/on или ip/off.
суть проблемы: что бы не покупать много датчиков, для тестирования и настройки, хочу заменить физический датчик на программу/сервер и т.п. где я смогу назначить ip и отправлять запросы.

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой задачей, или может подсказать, через что ее можно решить?

Comment: Можно написать программу на Python, которая будет эмулировать поведение физического датчика. Понадобится библиотека для работы с протоколом HTTP, Flask(для пет проекта мне кажется самое то). Так же можно создать веб-сервер на вашем компьютере и назначить ему определенный IP-адрес, который будет в программе для отправки запросов вместо IP-адреса датчика.
После вам нужно создать несколько эндпоинтов на сервере, которые будут отвечать на запросы вида "ip/on" и "ip/off". Ответ сервер должен отправлять сигналы виртуальному датчику, чтобы он имитировал переключение на нужное состояние.

Comment: спасибо. буду пробовать. направление понятно. я читал про mock server, но мне кажется это не совсем то

Comment: Чтобы просто имитировать ответы по http, не обязательно писать свой сервер. Можно использовать https://pypi.org/project/responses/

Answer (score 2):

Для эмуляции физических датчиков можно использовать программное обеспечение, которое эмулирует работу этих датчиков по протоколу, который они используют для обмена данными. Например, если ваши физические датчики используют протокол HTTP, вы можете написать программу, которая эмулирует сервер и отвечает на запросы типа ip/on или ip/off.

Для реализации этого можно использовать любую языковую платформу, которая поддерживает работу с сетью, например, Python, Java или Node.js.

Например, в Python вы можете использовать библиотеку Flask, чтобы создать сервер, который будет обрабатывать запросы по определенному адресу и возвращать соответствующие ответы. Пример кода на Flask:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/<ip>/<action>')
def control_device(ip, action):
    # здесь можно написать логику, которая будет эмулировать работу датчика
    # в зависимости от полученных параметров
    return f'IP {ip} turned {action}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()’
```